# Firebase/Firestore is not refreshing data correct

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

i'm working on a app with react-native/expo and try to fetch data from Firestore.

In my database sturcture i have a collection called "users". This collection holds user documents. Every user have a subcollection "userEvents", which holds references to the events they have subscribed

I'm able to get the data from the collection, but if some changes occurs my screens are not refreshing correct.

I fetch the data with:

```
onCollectionUpdate(uid){
this.setState({events: '', isLoading: true})
  let userCollection = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).collection("uEvents");
  userCollection.onSnapshot(snapshot =>{   
    Promise.all(
      snapshot.docs.map(snap =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          const data = snap.data()
          const visited = data.visited

          data.eventRef.onSnapshot(doc =>{
            let eventData = doc.data()
            let object ={
              id: doc.id,
              visited: visited,
              title: eventData.title,
              picture: eventData.picture,
              password: eventData.password,
              eventCode: eventData.eventCode,
              description: eventData.description
            }
            resolve(object)
          })
        })
      })
    ).then(data =>{
      this.setState({events: data, isLoading: false})
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
})
}
```

and call the function with:

```
    this.unsubscribe = this.onCollectionUpdate(this.state.currentUser.uid)
```

When i delete an event from the uEvent Collection always the last item disappears till i reopen the app. If i add a new event always the last item is shown two times.

Would be nice if someone can help me or give me a hint